keycloak error has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin
I'm trying to log in via API from an ExpressJS client on Keycloak on a different server but it keeps giving me the error "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ."
Searching online they say to set "*" to Web origin in Realm settings, but in my version that field is not there.
What can I do? Thank you
currently i am using keycloak version 24.0.4. how i fix it for this version
